# supporting files in epub3 (pdf, word, excel)

Tags: epub3

If anyone can troubleshoot my questions below:

We've included the supporting files like (pdf, word document, excel spreadsheet) along with the epub3 package and provided the respective link in XHTML files, when clicking the links for respective documents in HTML file it works fine in iPad devices.

Also, it allows the same to open in ADE 4.5 as well as in Readium, but the ADE is quitting while the document is attempting to open. Redium has no response after the document is opened.

It will be greatful, if anyone resolves this issue at the earliest.

Thanks,
Raj.

Answer (score 0):

While the EPUB 3 specification allows you to embed arbitrary files inside the OCF container (i.e., the ZIP file that makes the "external shell" of the EPUB), it does not require that the Reading Application should be able to "understand" what those files are, and "display" them or "act" upon them according to the semantics that are inherent to each file format.

In short: the EPUB 3 Reading Applications are not required to be able to do anything with PDF, Word, Excel files embedded inside an EPUB file. The fact that iBooks on iOS does something meaningful with them is just a choice of iBooks' developers.